# cython wrap cpp structs and function with parameter an array of structs

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am using Cython to wrap a c++ library in python. Unfortunately, I have no access to the c++ library. Therefore, I have to find somehow a way to wrap the structures and functions as exposed by the lib API.

My question regards the best way to wrap a c++ structure and; subsequently, how to create a memory view in python and pass its pointer (first element address) to a c++ function with parameter an array of cpp structures.

For example, let say I have the following h file:

```cpp
//test.h

struct cxxTestData
{
   int m_id;
   double m_value;
};

void processData(cxxTestData* array_of_test_data, int isizeArr)
```

My pyx file will look like the following

```cy
cdef extern from "Test.h":
    cdef struct cxxTestData:
        int m_id
        double m_value

cdef class pyTestData:
    cdef cxxTestData cstr

    def __init__(self, id, value):
        self.cstr.m_id = id
        self.cstr.m_value = value

    @property
    def ID(self):
        return self.cstr.m_id

    @property
    def Value(self):
        return self.cstr.m_value
```

Now, I want to create a number of pyTestData and store them in an array of dtype object. Then I want to pass this array as memory view in a cython/python function.

The wrapping function will have the following signature

```cy
cpdef void pyProcessData(pyTestData[::1] test_data_arr)
```

I have tested the above and it compiles successfully. I managed also to modify the members of each structure. However, this is not what I am trying to achieve. My question is how from this point I can pass an array with the c++ structures encapsulated in each pyTestData object (via the self.cstr).

As an example please have a look to the following listing:

```cy
cpdef void pyProcessData(pyTestData[::1] test_data_arr):
    cdef int isize test_data_arr.shape[0]

    # here I want to create/insert an array of type cxxTestData to pass it 
    # to the cpp function
    # In other words, I want to create an array of [test_data_arr.cstr]
    # I guess I can use cxxTestData[::1] or cxxTestData* via malloc and
    # copy each test_data_arr[i].cstr to this new array
    cdef cxxTestData* testarray = <cxxTestData*>malloc(isize*sizeof(cxxTestData))

    cdef int i
    for i in range(isize):
        testarray[i] = test_data_arr[i].cstr
    processData(&testarray[0], isize)

    for i in range(isize):
        arrcntrs[i].pystr = testarray[i]

    free(testarray)
```

Has anyone come across with such a case? Is there any better way to pass my python objects in the above function without having to copy over the cxx structures internally?

Many thanks in advance and apologies if I do something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: 1) I don't think `pyTestData[::1]` really works - it will actually accept any array of `object`s without complaint. I'm sure it didn't used to compile at all, so compiling and not doing what you want feels like a regression. 2) The fundamental issue is that `pyTestData` are Python objects, so must be allocated individually and also contain Python reference counting data. Therefore, there isn't a solid block of c++ objects for you to send to your function (without copying).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Actually, pyTestData[::1] does compile. However, I agree that it accepts any array of objects. Therefore, not the best for storing my objects. Do I have to define the dtype explicitly (pyTestDataType = [('m_id', 'int'), ('m_value', 'double')]) and then use it to my signature so as to accept only these objects? Could you provide an example? This is not the real question; however, it could help me to do all things correct.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really have a good solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want an array of `cxxTestData` to pass to your C++ functions, the best thing to do is to allocate it as an array. Some untested code that illustrates the approach:

```
cdef class TestDataArray:
    cdef cxxTestData* array:
    def __init__(self, int length):
        self.array = <cxxTestData*>calloc(length,sizeof(cxxTestData))
    def __dealloc__(self):
        free(self.array)
    def __getitem__(self, int idx):
        return PyTestData.from_pointer(&self.array[idx],self) # see later
    def __setitem__(self, int idx, PyTestData pyobj): # this is optional
        self.array[idx] = deref(pyobj.cstr)
```

You then want to slightly modify your `PyTestData` class so that it holds a pointer rather than holding the class directly. It should also have a field representing the ultimate owner of the data (e.g. the array). This ensures the array is kept alive, and can also allow for the case where the `PyTestData` owns its own data:

```
cdef class PyTestData:
    cdef cxxTestData* cstr
    cdef object owner

    def __init__(self, id, value):
        self.owner = None
        self.cstr = <cxxTestData*>malloc(sizeof(cxxTestData))
        self.cstr.m_id = id
        self.cstr.m_value = value

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self.owner is None: # i.e. this class owns it
             free(self.cstr)

    @staticmethod
    cdef PyTestData from_pointer(cxxTestData* ptr, owner):
        # calling __new__ avoids calling the constructor
        cdef PyTestData x = PyTestData.__new__(PyTestData)
        x.owner = owner
        x.cstr = ptr
        return x
```

There is a little extra effort in creating the `TestDataArray` class, but it stores the data in a format directly usable from C++, and so I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Hi David, many thanks for the illustrative example. So, the TestDataArray is an additional wrapper class that stores my cxx structures, right? And with a __setitem__ I can fill my array.

Comment: Yes, `TestDataArray` is an additional wrapper. I'd probably use `__getitem__` and then change the data in place instead of using `__setitem__` (just because `__setitem__` involves more copying, which you seemed to be trying to avoid).

Comment: How do you fill the array with the __getitem__? I thought I would have to use a setter method to fill my cxxTestData array.

Comment: When you call `__getitem__` it returns a `PyTestData` that shares data with part of the array. Therefore if you change the elements of that `PyTestData` then it also changes the array.

Comment: I see. However, I my case I need to copy/fill my array with some instatiated `pyTestData` objects and then pass the array to the solver (`processData`). I tested your code and it works really nice. I will edit some minor parts only. Please review. Many thanks once again for your valuable advice.

Comment: Most of your edit looks fine. I kept `calloc` because it zero-initialises things (but I corrected the line)